# How can I refactor this simple Ruby snippet?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Base < Library
  prelude "some-value"        # from Library
  def foo; ...; end

  prelude "some-other-value"  # from Library
  def bar; ...; end

  # ... others
end
```

I'd like to refactor it into something like the following:

```
class Base < Library
  # what goes here to bring FooSupport and BarSupport in?
end

class FooSupport (< ... inherit from something?)
  prelude "..."   # Need a way to get Library prelude.
  def foo; ...; end
end

class BarSupport (< ... inherit from something?)
  prelude "..."   # Need a way to get Library prelude.
  def bar; ...; end
end
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `include`. You may have used it before in modules, but it works in classes too, since Class inherits from Module in Ruby. Place your support methods in a module and `include` them in your main class.

As for the `prelude` class method, simply call that on the object you’re given in the module’s `included` method.

**base.rb:**

```
require "foo"
require "bar"

class Base < Library
  include FooSupport
  include BarSupport
end
```

**foo.rb:**

```
module FooSupport
  def self.included (klass)
    klass.prelude "..."
  end

  def foo; "..." end
end
```

---

**Edit:** If you need to intersperse calls to `prelude` and method definitions, you may need to use something more like this:

```
module FooSupport
  def self.included (klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      prelude "..."
      def foo; "..." end

      prelude "..."
      def bar; "..." end
    end
  end
end
```